# Toggle dropdown menus for different menu items with Jquery

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, object-oriented

In a bigger project of mine I'm using angular to create a dropdown menu dynamically and then toggling a dropdown menu for some of the menu items. This is why I got a function that toggles the dropdown menus for only the items that should actually have one. However, I feel like I should try to DRY this out a bit since I'll be repeating the same function even more than what I've done so far. How can I improve this code? Should I create a self invoking function or something similar?

Here's the functions (they're part of a controller object that I left out):

```
    init: function() {

        menuController.toggleDropDown('msg');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('mypages');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('tools');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('administration');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('contactinfo');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('utbildning');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('surveys');
        menuController.toggleDropDown('help');
    },
    toggleDropDown: function (id) {

        $('#main-menu' + ' #' + id + '').hover(function() {
            $('#' + id + ' ul').stop().slideToggle();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use html attribute to group it.

eg.

```
<div data-toggle="dropdown"> or
<a data-toggle="dropdown"> or whatever
```

and then

```
$('#main-menu [data-toggle="dropdown"]').hover(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').stop().slideToggle();
});
```